# WSO2 IdentityServer row-level security

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does anybody use WSO2 Identity Server for implementation of row-level security? What would the performance of policies be like in that case? If I will have more than 1,000,000 policies that define security behavior for concrete data row, would that be a bottleneck? Do any patterns exist for row-level security and WSO2 Identity Server?